# Jekyll Install via RubyGems, Permissions Issue on usr/bin

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to install Jekyll via RubyGems on macOS 10.11.6 (15G1611), but getting a permission error. Unable to sudo chmod to change it (SIP locked directory...)

```
$ install jekyll  
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)  
You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

Comment: You can try to use a ruby versioning manager like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). Read carefully and it can be a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Install jekyll system wide with `sudo`.

```
 sudo gem install jekyll
```

Or create a sandboxed instance with bundler:

```
 bundle init
```

edit `Gemfile` with this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "jekyll"
```

and install it:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Comment: Updating ruby gems helped, using the latest now for dev project and works fine.